# Rotate the custom view?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I've some drawings on my custom view, want to let users rotate it

viewContorller.m:

```
-(void)setMyView:(myView *)myView {
...
    [self.faceView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:faceView action:@selector(rotate:)]];
...
}
```

faceView.m

```
- (void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(gesture.rotation);
        gesture.rotation = 0;
    }
}
```

It just not work, but quite shaking?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code and also add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in viewController.h class.

```
-(void)setMyView:(myView *)myView {
//...
        UIRotationGestureRecognizer* rotateRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
        rotateRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.faceView addGestureRecognizer:rotateRecognizer];

//...
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is with your rotate method, try this code,

```
- (void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, [gesture rotation]);
        gesture.rotation = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this before, it scaling when it is rotating, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to rotate your view ,enable userinteraction and multi touch enable on you view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    [self.myview addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];
}

- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}

- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}
```

This code is from apples sample code [touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435).

Comment: It scaling when it is rotating.

Comment: i dont understand what r u saying ,can you explain.

Comment: It just become bigger when approaching k*90 degrees and smaller when approaching k*45 degrees while I rotating it! (also get lots of things on the console)

Comment: I downloaded the sample code, it works fine actually..(the sample code)

Comment: it does not scaling ,it display like this bcoz your view is not exact square ,so when it become horizontal than it will display larger than vertical.and i dont get any log value.can you put your log value in comment.

Comment: I set the background color, check this:http://s8.postimage.org/lygjq6f3n/2013_02_26_3_31_19.png 
log:http://i.imgur.com/nXBPvn2.png

Comment: I have simulate your scenario with my app and i dont get any log info, i think its bcoz of that faceview on the rottating view check its code.